# Prisma client is not recognized using TypeScript and Express

Tags: typescript, prisma

I have a problem that appeared recently when I restructured the express project into folders of the src type
I keep getting this error in my typescript files

```
Cannot resolve symbol 'PrismaClient'
```

My structure

```
/main_folder
 /src
 /prisma
 /node_modules
```

my ts.config

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6" /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', 'ES2018', 'ES2019', 'ES2020', or 'ESNEXT'. */,
    "module": "commonjs" /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', 'es2020', or 'ESNext'. */,
    "outDir": "./dist" /* Redirect output structure to the directory. */,
    "strict": true /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */,
    "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types"] /* List of folders to include type definitions from. */,
    "esModuleInterop": true /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */,
    "skipLibCheck": true /* Skip type checking of declaration files. */,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true /* Disallow inconsistently-cased references to the same file. */,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "allowJs": true
  }
}
```

And in the files I import the client like this

```
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";
```

I tried to generate again, but that doesn't help

Comment: What package manager are you using? npm, pnpm, yarn?
I was able to find this related GitHub Issue: https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/13946
Could you try suggestions mentioned there?

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue in my PHPStorm 2022.1.4. Tough IDE complained about it, prisma was working. If you update IDE version it will start support typescript v5.